# Objective c: iBeacon ranging doesn't fire didEnterRegion

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I´ve implemented a beacon region monitoring in my AppDelegate.

I test my code in foreground.
The didRangeBeacons event is thrown successfully and regularly. (I see the amount of beacons and also the count change in the didRangeBeacons if i turn off my beacon.)
My didEnterRegion event was not fired.

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //....
    self->beaconLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self->beaconLocationManager.delegate = self;//(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSUUID *uuid=[[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:@"200F0B26-2215-1518-442B-5F0616412530"];
    clBeconRegion=[[CLBeaconRegion alloc]initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"BluetoothExample"];
    clBeconRegion.notifyOnEntry=YES;
    [self->beaconLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [self->beaconLocationManager startMonitoringForRegion:clBeconRegion];
    [self->beaconLocationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:clBeconRegion];
    return YES;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"ENTER REGION");//not fired
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{
    NSLog(@"beacons list %@ ",beacons);//successfully fired regularly
}
```

- I also enabled Background App Refresh in general settings.
- Info.plist entry:
  `<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key><string>bla bla bla</string>
  <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key><string>bla bla bla</string>`
- [image: Activated background mode]

The monitoringDidFailForRegion writes the following error:
`CLBeaconRegion (identifier:'BluetoothExample', uuid:200F0B26-2215-1518-442B-5F0616412530, major:(null), minor:(null)) The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 4.)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable BLE background permission as well.
Go to `Project Target` >> `Background Modes` >> `Capabilities`  check Uses `Bluetooth LE Accessories`. Look on this Image[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.
It is an existing app and I granted the location in a fewer version only for "in usage".
Now I need "always".

I deleted an reinstalled the app and it works. (only update doesn't help)

Comment: Indeed.  A new change in iOS 11 blocks beacon monitoring callbacks unless the location "always" permission is granted to the app.  The "when in use" permission is sufficient for ranging but not monitoring.